# How to solve DbUpdateConcurrencyException when updating a row?

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I'm using the entity framework code first approach for an ASP.NET MVC application.  After editing a row when submitting for saving the change I'm getting the following error for the http post method:

> An exception of type
>   'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateConcurrencyException'
>   occurred in EntityFramework.dll but was not handled in user code.

This error is encountered at db.SaveChanges().

```
db.Entry<Project>(EditedProj).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;
db.SaveChanges();
```

Main code:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Edit(int id)
{
    using (var db = new ProjectContext())
    {
        return View(db.Projects.Find(id));
    }
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(Project EditedProj)
{
    using (var db = new ProjectContext())
    {
        db.Entry<Project>(EditedProj).State = 
             System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Projects");
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you probably wanted your code to say:

return Edit(db.Projects.Find(id));

Answer (score 16):

I have found the answer.  I was not passing id value for Http Post action method.

As stated in this [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.infrastructure.dbupdateconcurrencyexception%28v=vs.113%29.aspx)

> Exception thrown by DbContext when it was expected that SaveChanges for an entity would result in a database update but in fact no rows in the database were affected.

In my case the above statement is true because I was trying to update a row but without id no row was updated. Hence, the exception.

It can be done using a hidden input element which contains the id. The code below shows how to do it in Edit.cshtml –

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Edit", "Home", FormMethod.Post,
    new { @class = "form-horizontal", role = "form" }))
{
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.ProjectID)
    //Other code … … …
}
```

Comment: why do you have int id on edit form and model itself with id field?