# How to implement the Web API Put controller to support primary key column updated (cascading update)

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework-4, asp.net-web-api2

I am working on a Web API and AngularJS, I am having an issue with the `Put` method. When I want to update any other column, it works fine, but if I try to update the primary key column (i.e the `employeeID`), it fails.

However in the database, it allows cascading update. How can I improve the `Put` function to update by `employeeID`?

```
// PUT: api/Employee/5
public HttpResponseMessage Put(Employee emp)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        this.emp.Entry(emp).State = EntityState.Modified;
        this.emp.SaveChanges();

        HttpResponseMessage res = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, emp);
        return res;
    }
    else
    {
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, emp);
    }
}
```

Thanks!!

Comment: *How* does it fail? Do you get an error message? If so: *what* error message?? Please post it here - after all, we cannot see your screen, nor read your mind ...

Answer (score 0):

Check if your employeeID is auto increment. If it is then it wont allow you to insert or update that specific field.

Comment: this is the error


An exception of type 'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateConcurrencyException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Store update, insert, or delete statement affected an unexpected number of rows (0). Entities may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=472540 for information on understanding and handling optimistic concurrency exceptions.

Comment: Are you sure your Id is getting passed through as well? see if this link helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26148793/how-to-solve-dbupdateconcurrencyexception-when-updating-a-row