# MVC Crud Operation Edit

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to add a crud operation for editing an item in the database but I get this DbUpdateConcurrencyException. What might be the problem?
Thanks in advance.

CONTROLLER:

```
//MODAL POPUP FOR EDIT

public ActionResult EditItem()
{
  return PartialView();
}

//POST: EDIT ITEM

[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult EditItem(H_Table item)
{
  db_connection.Entry(item).State = EntityState.Modified;
  db_connection.SaveChanges();
  return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

Comment: This may help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26148793/how-to-solve-dbupdateconcurrencyexception-when-updating-a-row

Comment: How do you transfer the Id? Are there TimeStamp/RowVersion columns?  Also, this lacks all sorts of precautions.

Comment: Please show your Html view I think you are not passing item.

Comment: provide view code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically you have to check if your model is valid or not first then go through your update operation:

```
public ActionResult EditItem(H_Table item)
{
    if(ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        using (var db = new YourDbContext())
        {
            db.Entry(item).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges(); 
        }
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
}
```

However i suggest you find the item first by using Its Id, then fill an object of the same class by what you are getting from view model then insert that into database.

Answer (score 0):

Add your table name which you want to update in your database.

```
public ActionResult EditItem(H_Table item)
{
            H_Table oldObj= db.H_Table.Find(item.ID);
            db.Entry(oldObj).CurrentValues.SetValues(item);
            db_connection.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

Comment: Still doesn't work. <YourTableNameFromdbContext> doesn't play any role, since the database is connected. The controller already knows which table it is.

Comment: @SonOfAGun Check my updated answer. hope it will work.