# Cannot update record in entity framework

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, entity-framework, mvvm

The error message I get is this : DbUpdateConcurrencyException

I am using updating the IdentityRole table. I am using a ViewModel to display and capture data, then passing it back in, in my OnPost(). The data comes into my IdentityRole property as expected. I made sure the primary key is hidden in the form. I have also tried _context.Update(Role) in combination with SaveChanges() and i always get the same error. I also ensured i have the [BindProperty] on both my ViewModel and my IdentityRole properties.

Here is my Controller or code behind.

```
    public IActionResult OnPost()
    {
        Role.Name = RoleViewModel.RoleName;
        Role.NormalizedName = RoleViewModel.RoleName.ToUpper();
        Role.ConcurrencyStamp = DateTime.Now.ToString();

        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return Page();
        }

        _context.Entry(Role).Property(x => x.Name).IsModified = true;
        _context.Entry(Role).Property(x => x.NormalizedName).IsModified = true;
        _context.Entry(Role).Property(x => x.ConcurrencyStamp).IsModified = true;

        _context.SaveChanges();
        return Redirect("/Admin/HomeRole");
    }
```

My ViewModel

```
public class EditRoleViewModel
{
    public EditRoleViewModel()
    {
        Users = new List<string>();
    }

    public string Id { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Role Name is required")]
    public string RoleName { get; set; }

    public List<string> Users { get; set; }
}
```

Here is the form

```
    <form method="post" class="mt-3">
        <input asp-for="RoleViewModel.Id" type="hidden" />
        <input asp-for="RoleViewModel.Users" type="hidden" />
        <div class="form-group row">
            <label asp-for="RoleViewModel.RoleName" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label"></label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
                <input asp-for="RoleViewModel.RoleName" class="form-control">
                <span asp-validation-for="RoleViewModel.RoleName" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Are you sure your model is picking up the ID?  This error is normally when EF was expecting a record to update in the DB but no rows were updated.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26148793/how-to-solve-dbupdateconcurrencyexception-when-updating-a-row

Comment: Yes I routed the model to my OnPost method and I am still getting the same error. I also checked the Id of the model i am routing and matched it up with the ID of the item I am changing and they do match.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the answer to my question

```
    public async Task<IActionResult> OnPost(EditRoleViewModel roleViewModel)
    {
        var role = await roleManager.FindByIdAsync(roleViewModel.Id);

        role.Name = roleViewModel.RoleName;

        var result = await roleManager.UpdateAsync(role);

        return Page();
    }
```

Comment: How is this the answer to your question?  Please give more detail.

Answer (score 0):

From what I see in your question, you need to pass the Id for Http Post. I understand that you are hiding the Id in the form but you need pass it to the controller and then to the Model to save. So, something like below,

```
public IActionResult OnPost(RoleViewModel model){......}
```

then assign the Id. If you are updating the row with no Id, then you will get this exception in DbContext.

[For further reading in MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.infrastructure.dbupdateconcurrencyexception?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=entity-framework-6.2.0)

[Asp.Net controller snippets](https://jonhilton.net/2017/08/17/how-to-get-data-from-an-html-form-to-your-asp.net-mvc-core-controller/)

Check these too. Try and let me know.

Comment: I routed the model to my OnPost method and I still get the same error. I read the MSDN article and it says "This usually indicates that the database has been concurrently updated such that a concurrency token that was expected to match did not actually match." which makes sense, but I would assume that would be my primary key, and it does match and isn't changed.